# I want to loop through an array but I don't want to use for

Tags: javascript, each

```
function CreateSuspectObjects(name){
    return {
        name: name,
        color: name.split(' ')[1],
        speak(){
            console.log("my name is" , name);
        } 
    };
};
```

A function that takes name as value and return it as an object.

```
var suspects = ['miss scarlet','colonel mustard','mr white'];

var suspectsList = [];

var _ = {};
```

I get error whether I create this var or not. I don't know why.

```
_.each(suspects , function(name){
    let suspectObj= CreateSuspectObjects(name);
    suspectsList.push(suspectObj);
});
```

I used each because I didn't want to use for.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: _.each is not a function
    at <anonymous>:15:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` for this. In your case:

```
suspects.map((name) => {
    let suspectObj= CreateSuspectObjects(name);
    suspectsList.push(suspectObj);
});
```

If you need the index in the future you can also do:

```
suspects.map((name, idx) => {
    let suspectObj= CreateSuspectObjects(name);
    suspectsList.push(suspectObj);
});
```

Comment: thank you so much and how can i solve this with each ?

Comment: Do you mean the jquery `$(selector).each()`? If so that only applies to DOM elements

Comment: alright thank you i am a newbie idk much things sorry for that.

Comment: @christian-plourde: doesn't JavaScript have `Array.prototype.forEach` now natively?

Answer (score 0):

You could do `Array.from`:

```js
function CreateSuspectObjects(name){
    return {
        name: name,
        color: name.split(' ')[1],
        speak(){
            console.log("my name is" , name);
        } 
    };
};
var suspects = ['miss scarlet','colonel mustard','mr white'];
var suspectsList = [];
window.addEventListener(`load`, () => {
    const p = document.getElementById(`output`);
    suspectsList = Array.from(suspects, e => CreateSuspectObjects(e));
    p.innerHTML = Array.from(suspectsList, e => JSON.stringify(e)).join(`<br />`); // Just for formatting, not needed
});
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```